# how to figure out a button visible and invisible when login and logout in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, button

I want to show a button visible on the home page of my website when I log in 
and make it invisible when I log out 
how can I do it in wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress have a function to check if a user is logged in use it check at codex

Comment: but I want to do some actions after login

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As I have said in the comment wordpress does provide a function that checks if user is logged in that function is `is_user_logged_in()` you can use this function to check if the current website visitor is logged in or not if its logged in then you can display a personal message or what ever that you only want loggedin users to see.

So on your home page template where u want to display the button for a loggedin user do this :

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {?>
        <form method="Post" action="somepage.php">

            <button type="submit">Button Text</button>
        </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it was helpful
now I'm gonna change it to recognize some of the users who have a specific roles

Comment: great, u can mark the answer,  remember wp have a function to check roles already the function is `current_user_can('role')`